# Replace time value inside a programming code using Excel VBA or Javascript

Tags: javascript, vba, excel

I am trying to make scrolling karaoke lyrics of a song. The lyric software outputs a code which contains time in seconds that I need to convert.

I Have two versions of the same song. One runs in 52 bpm (beats per minute) which is a slower version and another runs at 104 bpm which is faster version.

I have completed the first version which took hell lot of a time. I want to convert the code in such a way that I can get the faster version automatically.

Here is the sample code

```
<item dStartTime="4" dEndTime="8" n3DRhythm="2" str3DSceneLayoutFile="">    
    <text>Batti Gul Meter Chalu</text>
</item> 
<item dStartTime="9.52" dEndTime="14.47" n3DRhythm="2" str3DSceneLayoutFile=""> 
    <text>rajj&lt;10.44&gt; ke&lt;10.99&gt; rulaya</text>
</item> 
<item dStartTime="14.47" dEndTime="19.06" n3DRhythm="2" str3DSceneLayoutFile="">    
    <text>rajj ke&lt;15.94&gt; hansaya</text>
</item>
```

I want to convert the same code as shown below where the time in seconds should be exactly half with two decimal points

```
<item dStartTime="2" dEndTime="4" n3DRhythm="2" str3DSceneLayoutFile="">    
    <text>Batti Gul Meter Chalu</text>
</item> 
<item dStartTime="4.76" dEndTime="7.24" n3DRhythm="2" str3DSceneLayoutFile="">  
    <text>rajj&lt;5.22&gt; ke&lt;5.50&gt; rulaya</text>
</item> 
<item dStartTime="7.24" dEndTime="9.53" n3DRhythm="2" str3DSceneLayoutFile="">  
    <text>rajj ke&lt;7.97&gt; hansaya</text>
</item>
```

I took the code in MS Excel and tried using substitute, concatenate and other few formulas to achieve what I need but I am unable to do so and though excel vba can help but I cannot do it in vba. Request you guys to help me out in this as I need to convert a lot of songs. Your kind assistance will save a lot of time. Any help in excel vba, javascript or any other way to replace the code.

In the `<item>` section, I need to convert the `dStartTime` and `dEndTime`

In the `<text>` section, I need to convert anything that looks like a number

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript, you can use `DOMParser` to convert the string into a document, after which you can iterate over each `<item>`, change the `dStartTime` and `dEndTime` attributes, and then change any numbers in the child `<text>` node:

```js
const str = `<item dStartTime="4" dEndTime="8" n3DRhythm="2" str3DSceneLayoutFile="">    
    <text>Batti Gul Meter Chalu</text>
</item> 
<item dStartTime="9.52" dEndTime="14.47" n3DRhythm="2" str3DSceneLayoutFile=""> 
    <text>rajj&lt;10.44&gt; ke&lt;10.99&gt; rulaya</text>
</item> 
<item dStartTime="14.47" dEndTime="19.06" n3DRhythm="2" str3DSceneLayoutFile="">    
    <text>rajj ke&lt;15.94&gt; hansaya</text>
</item> `;

const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'text/html');
const halve = num => Math.round(100 * num / 2) / 100;
const halveAttrib = (node, name) => {
  const newVal = halve(node.getAttribute(name))
  node.setAttribute(name, newVal);
};

doc.querySelectorAll('item').forEach((item) => {
  halveAttrib(item, 'dStartTime');
  halveAttrib(item, 'dEndTime');
  item.children[0].textContent = item.children[0].textContent
    .replace(/\d+(\.\d+)/g, num => halve(num).toFixed(2));
});

const output = doc.body.innerHTML
  .replace(/dstarttime/g, 'dStartTime')
  .replace(/dendtime/g, 'dEndTime')
  .replace(/n3drhythm/g, 'n3DRhythm')
  .replace(/str3dscenelayoutfile/g, 'str3DSceneLayoutFile');
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. it works but there are two things I need to ask. The code is converted properly but when i import in the lyric software it does not work and I found the reason for it. It requires  `dstarttime` as `dStartTime`and `dendtime` as `dEndTime` as it is case sensitive. What changes do we need to make it so that the code outputs in this fashion?.... 2. Is there any online website where I can put the code in one side and get the result on another side like how you have done in Run Code Snippet?

Comment: It looks like the attributes get automatically converted to lower case, but the fix is easy with a regular expression.

Comment: You can use any online editor like JSFiddle, or even a stack snippet here, or just your browser console.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind assistance. God bless !

Answer (score 1):

This uses a DOM parser to write out the  values and duration after reading each section of HTML from an html file. I struggled with accessing the Text nodes so have had to hack my way around that which I am not best pleased with. It does mean you know the value you are searching for which means you can do a replace on the html string by using regex .Replace method. For dStartTime and dendTime you can do a straight replace on the outerHTML. This replace just in the current HTMLDocument unless you write back out to file. SetAttribute doesn't work in this instance. I am not sure why I couldn't access the text nodes, particularly as don't have source HTMLDocument. Would be good to see if someone can solve that.

```
item.outerHTML = Replace$(item.outerHTML, "dstarttime=" & Chr$(34) & item.dstarttime & Chr$(34), "dstarttime=" & 666 & Chr$(34)) 'example  666 as replace value.
```

vba:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetValues()
    'VBE > Tools > References > HTML Object Library
    Dim html As HTMLDocument
    Debug.Print "doc1", vbNewLine
    Set html = GetHTMLFileContent("C:\Users\User\Desktop\test.html") 'first html document. Info saved in text file with .html extension
    GetItems html
    Debug.Print "doc2", vbNewLine
    Set html = GetHTMLFileContent("C:\Users\User\Desktop\test2.html") 'second html document. Info saved in text file with .html extension
    GetItems html
End Sub
Public Sub GetItems(ByVal html As HTMLDocument)
    Dim items As Object, item As Object, counter As Long
    Set items = html.getElementsByTagName("item")
    For Each item In items
        Debug.Print " item " & counter + 1
        Dim itemArr() As String
        itemArr = Split(html.body.innerHTML, "</ITEM")
        Debug.Print "startTime = " & Round(item.dStartTime, 2), "endTime = " & Round(item.dendTime, 2), "duration : " & Round(item.dendTime - item.dStartTime, 2)
        Debug.Print "Associated text numbers "
        On Error Resume Next
        GetTextAttributeNumbers Split(itemArr(counter), "<TEXT>")(1)
        On Error GoTo 0
        counter = counter + 1
    Next item
End Sub


Public Sub GetTextAttributeNumbers(ByVal inputString As String)
    Dim matches As Object, iMatch As Object

    With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = "\d{1,}(\.\d+)?"
        If .TEST(inputString) Then
            Set matches = .Execute(inputString)
            For Each iMatch In matches
                Debug.Print iMatch

            Next iMatch
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Public Function GetHTMLFileContent(ByVal filePath As String) As HTMLDocument
    '"C:\Users\HarrisQ\Desktop\test.html"
    Dim fso As Object, hFile As Object, hString As String, html As New HTMLDocument
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set hFile = fso.OpenTextFile(filePath)

    Do Until hFile.AtEndOfStream
        hString = hFile.ReadAll()
    Loop

    html.body.innerHTML = hString
    Set GetHTMLFileContent = html
End Function
```

---

To properly parse the documents the following syntax is required:

Doc1

```html
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <item dstarttime="4" dendtime="8" n3drhythm="2" str3dscenelayoutfile=""> 
   <text>
    Batti Gul Meter Chalu
   </text> 
  </item> 
  <item dstarttime="9.52" dendtime="14.47" n3drhythm="2" str3dscenelayoutfile=""> 
   <text>
    rajj&lt;10.44&gt; ke&lt;10.99&gt; rulaya
   </text> 
  </item> 
  <item dstarttime="14.47" dendtime="19.06" n3drhythm="2" str3dscenelayoutfile=""> 
   <text>
    rajj ke&lt;15.94&gt; hansaya
   </text> 
  </item> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Doc2

```html
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <item dstarttime="2" dendtime="4" n3drhythm="2" str3dscenelayoutfile=""> 
   <text>
    Batti Gul Meter Chalu
   </text> 
  </item> 
  <item dstarttime="4.76" dendtime="7.24" n3drhythm="2" str3dscenelayoutfile=""> 
   <text>
    rajj&lt;5.22&gt; ke&lt;5.50&gt; rulaya
   </text> 
  </item> 
  <item dstarttime="7.24" dendtime="9.53" n3drhythm="2" str3dscenelayoutfile=""> 
   <text>
    rajj ke&lt;7.97&gt; hansaya
   </text> 
  </item> 
 </body>
</html>
```

---

This means, if not present, concantentating the missing start and end strings.

```
"<html><head></head><body>" &  yourHTMLString & "</body>
</html>"
```

---

**Example output from second document:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am trying to understand how to use this code as I am struggling to get the result in test2.html as it is blank

Comment: It works fine from my end. Do you have saved in two docs with the appropriate names?

Comment: i made two files. 1.html and kept it in D:\ root folder which has the code and another file 2.html at the same location which I kept it blank thinking that it will get the values automatically after the code is processed. And then I changed the path in the sub routine. I am doing anything wrong?

Comment: Oh.. actually second file seems to miss one value. The html you have shown goes in two separate text files which you save as .html. Then read those files in.

Comment: you need HTML tags to properly parse the second.

Comment: I am writing the results to the immediate window. Ctrl + G to view from VBE. Note, I am reading your string in from html files but you can just create an html document and add your string with the concatenation.

Comment: understood.... I have corrected everything and I may have to modify a bit to suit my needs. Thank you so very much for your efforts. God bless !

Comment: Pleasure. Glad to have helped.